# For which $\alpha$ does $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^{\alpha}}\,dx$ converge?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

> Find the range of value of $\alpha $ for which $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^{\alpha}}$ is convergent.

My attempts:  $$\sin x \le 1\implies\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^{\alpha}}\le \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}$$

So $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^{\alpha}}$ is convergent if $\alpha > 0$.

Comment: $\int_0^\infty 1/x^a \,dx$ is NOT convergent for any $a>0$.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke...can u give me any hints ?

Comment: You have potential divergences both at infinity and at the origin. The origin is the easier of the two to handle... what does $\sin(x)/x^\alpha$ look like at the origin?